# Sending out of office notification to reply-to

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

Customers can contact our employees via a contact form on the profile page of each employee. When the form is submitted, the employee receives a notification e-mail. The sender of this e-mail (From) is always info@mycompany.com. The entered address of the website visitor is stored as reply-to.

However, if the employee has activated an out of office notification, it will be sent to info@mycompany.com instead of the intended reply-to address.

Due to SPF and DMARC, we cannot use the website visitor's e-mail address as the from address.
Is there a way to instruct Exchange Online to use the reply-to address or can we define a header in the notification e-mail, for example?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from AndyDavid in the Microsoft forums, we now use the visitor's address as the from address after all. Using an Exchange mail flow rule, we deactivate the spam check on our mail server and thus avoid possible problems with failed SPF checks.

You can find my thread in the [Microsoft forums](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/90300/sending-out-of-office-notification-to-reply-to.html)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, it's also benefited me a lot. At the same time, you could mark this best answer to help others who have the same problem.